# iOS 7 - is there a way to disable the swipe back and forward functionality in Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, ios7

For some web pages we use the swipe left and right functionality of iPhone to pull up the menus. 
Now with iOS7, they have introduced the ability to go back and forward to previous and next pages of browser history on swipe left and right motions.

But is there a way to disable it for specific pages so as to not have conflicting behavior on the swipe actions?

Comment: It should be distinguished by the swipe starting offscreen. Do you have an example webpage where a conflict occurs?

Comment: @RupertRawnsley Add a touchstart/touchmove event to your web page with a console.log('FIRED!'); in it. Move your finger onto the web page from the edge and you will notice the event never fires.


Am I right in assuming that this will be the new expected behavior?

Comment: @Marcus That sounds like the expected behaviour. I suppose swipe events will only work if they start within some safety margin of the browser window. Technically this is understandable, but the user experience is going to be a bit confusing. The article Vinzzz links to in the answer below correctly points out this is not just a Safari issue.

Comment: Has anything changed in regards to the history gesture in iOS8?  Has anyone gotten a change to play around with it?

Comment: I've filed an issue on Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1033464 I know this is an issue that affects more than a single browser, and the question was about Safari, but we have to start somewhere.

Comment: You can now (since iOS 13.4): https://stackoverflow.com/a/62308482/1774081

Answer (score 15):

No, this is done at the OS level, and webpage doesn't get any callback

See [this summary of safari changes in iOS7 that might cause problems to your website](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review) (including this swipe gesture)

Answer (score 13):

You can't disable it directly, but the native swipe back only happens if there is something in the browser history.

It won't work in every case, but if you have a single page web app opened in a new tab, you can prevent it from adding to the history by using

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "#" + url)
```

instead of pushState or

```
document.location.hash = url
```

Comment: Yes but this prevents only the history in the app itself when navigating. Other apps may also have pushed a history, therefore iOS will detect those histories too.

Answer (score 7):

I had to use 2 approaches:

**1) CSS only fix for Chrome/Firefox**

```css
html, body {
    overscroll-behavior-x: none;
}
```

**2) JavaScript fix for Safari**

```js
if (window.safari) {
    history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
        history.go(1);
    };
}
```

Over time, Safari will implement [overscroll-behavior-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior-x) and we'll be able to remove the JS hack

Comment: I added this and on Mac, it does prevent a left swipe from triggering back. However, it breaks the back functionality completely (incl. the Back button), so it can’t be used as a workaround.

Comment: In my case that was the goal as I was building a single page app

Comment: But it’s still possible that someone opens your app by clicking on a link on another website (i.e., if that site links to your app). To fix this, you’d still have to detect swipe gestures via `touchmove` events and only execute the above code if it *wasn’t* immediately preceded by a swipe. It should be possible.

Comment: I've updated this to include a CSS only option for Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Are you sure this works on iOS? I've just tested `overscroll-behavior-x: none;` on Chrome on iOS 13 and it had no effect to the swipe-navigation behaviour. Swiping right at the left edge goes back (and even if this is the first page in tab history, it still goes back to the home screen).

Comment: @naktinis on iOS is everything Safari under the hood so it won't work on it.

Answer (score 0):

If no history then no swipe.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  const a = evt.target.closest('a:not([href^="#"])');
    
  if (!a) { return; }

  evt.preventDefault(); 
  history.replaceState({ }, '', a.href);
  location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works in iOS 16:

```js
window.addEventListener('touchstart', e => e.preventDefault(), { passive: false })
```

`passive` flag is important!

I found that it also disables magnifying glass oh hover, maybe other Safari-specific events too.

Edit: this listener breaks other `onclick` event listeners from working...