# jQuery Mobile override default safari swipe behaviour

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

In ios7 safari apple introduced swiping navigation - swipe to the right sends windows.history.back() event and redirects to a previous page like user touched the back button.

In my app I am using right swipe to show left panel and I am using this code:(JQM 1.4.3 stable)

```
    <script>
    $( document ).on( "pageinit", ".ui-page", function() {
        $( document ).on( "swiperight", ".ui-page", function( e ) {
            if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                    $( ".panel" ).panel( "open" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

But instead of showing the panel safari rather uses it's default behaviour and loads the previous page. How to override this behaviour and show left panel?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889666/ios-7-is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-swipe-back-and-forward-functionality-in-sa